# Entity cannot coexist in two ICollections

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having troubles with my C# project (Visual Studio 2012, Entity Framework 6.0.2).

I have these entities in my db

```
public class Activity
{
    [Key]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Participant> Participants { get; set; }

    }

public class ActivityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Activity>
{
    public ActivityConfiguration()
    {
        ...
        HasMany(a => a.Participants).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasMany(a => a.Plans).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
}

//////////

public class Participant
{
    [Key]
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipantConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Participant>
{
    public ParticipantConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(p => p.Activities).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        ...
    }
}

//////////

public class ScheduleContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Participant> Participants { get; set; }

    public ScheduleContext()
    {
    }

    public ScheduleContext(String connectionString):base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ActivityConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ParticipantConfiguration());
        }
}
```

So I have this many-to-many relationship: Activity-Participant.
Now I can enroll a Participant p1 in an Activity a1 by the use of this function

```
public void Enroll(..., Participant p1, Activity a1)
{
    using (var db = new ScheduleContext(_connectionString))
    {
         //previously checking whether the participant is already enrolled 
         //in the given activity
         ....
         a1.Participants.Add(p1);
         p1.Activities.Add(a1);

         db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This works only when a participant is enrolled in a single activity; for instance, if I try to enroll the same Participant p1 in Activity a2 (where a1 is different from a2), the result is that p1 is removed from a1.Participants and is "moved" into a2.Participants.

I hope I was clear in this explanation of my problem and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Your mapping is not correct, what you're doing here is to define several "One To Many" relationships but you need to have a "Many To Many" relationship between Activity and Participant.

To do this, you have to do something like this on your "OnModelCreating" method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>()
   .HasMany<Participant>(a => a.Participants)
   .WithMany(p => p.Activities)
   .Map(m => {
       m.ToTable("ActivityParticipants");
       m.MapLeftKey("ActivityId");
       m.MapRightKey("ParticipantId");
    });
```

I hope it will help.

-------------- EDIT --------------

About your migrations issue:

First, you have to run this command on the Package Manager (PM) console:

```
Enable-Migrations
```

This will create a repository "Migrations" with a "Configuration.cs" file. Open this file and modify the configuration properties, edit the constructor as follow:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; // optional
}
```

Then, run the command "Update-Database" on PM console. The relation table "ActivityParticipants" should be created.

Comment: You're saying that i have to leave the table classes (activity and participant) as they are and just modify the OnModelCreating method? Because I'm trying to make it work but it gives me this horrible exception "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ActivityParticipants_dbo.Participants_ParticipantId' on table 'ActivityParticipants' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."

Comment: Yes, but you no longer need your EntityTypeConfigurations (for Activity and Participant) in your OnModelCreating method.
Don't forget that you need to do an "update-database" on your package manager console.

Comment: Thank you, I did exactly what you said, but this is not working, it countinues to raise that exception

Comment: You can check on adding ".WillCascadeOnDelete(false)" after the ".Map" method.

Comment: Ok, in this way it doesn't raise any exception, but i have the original problem (:S)

Comment: Hum ... are you sure that the relational table is created? And there is data inside her? (a1-p1 & a2-p1)

Comment: Aha! There is no such table, but I don't know what went wrong; as you said, when i look at the .edmx there are two one-to-many between activity and participant

Comment: This is strange, try to do an "update-database" then check if the table is created.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but when I try to execute the update-database command, it gives me this error: No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Test'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).